# Issues with submitting form with AJAX in Grails 2.0

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails, groovy, grails-2.0

In my GSP page, I have this form:

```
<g:form action="ajaxAdd">
  <g:textArea id='postContent' name="content" rows="3" cols="50"/><br/>
  <g:submitToRemote value="Post"
      url="[controller: 'post', action: 'addPostAjax']"
      update="allPosts"
  />            
</g:form>
```

And in the same page I have this div :

```
<div class="allPosts">
    <g:each in="${user.posts}" var="post">
        <div class="postEntry">
            <div class="postText">
                ${post.content}
            </div>
            <div class="classDate">
                ${post.dateCreated}
            </div>
        </div>
    </g:each>
</div>
```

When I click on the button, the application does fire the action `addPostAjax` in my controller but the problem is that I can't find out how to send back the `user.posts` collection in order to populate my `allPosts` div.

Does anyone have an idea please.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the `update` attribute on the `submitToRemote` tag, you need to send back the posts rendered.

First, make the div where you render user posts into a template e.g. `_userPosts.gsp`.  Replace the div in the page with a `render` tag to use the template:

```
<g:render template="userPosts" />
```

Then in your controller, the `addPostAjax` should look like this:

```
def addPostAjax() {
    def user = ....

    render template: 'userPosts', model: [user: user], contentType: "text/plain"
}
```

Another alternative is to `render user as JSON` and write some javascript to update your page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did that, and all the treatment inside the controller is done. But still the div doesn't want to be updated

Comment: The `update` attribute should specify the id of the div.  In your example, you need to add `id="allPosts"` instead of, or in addition to, `class="allPosts"`.